# Messaging between Android emulators stopped working after cleaning a project

Tags: android-studio

As in the title.
Now, if I send a message from an emulator to the other, the message is sent but is never received and no messaging code was changed by us at all.
What are the possible causes then?

Comment: Have you started again the emus? The problem persists?

Comment: Yep. I tried another project (older version of the same thing) and it worked. Which was unexpected. So I really have no idea where this originates from. Btw by not received I don't mean just by the Broadcast Receiver, I mean not received at all by the phone (not in the incoming SMS)